# jQuery populate text input from table based on select value in combination with multiple rows (parent function?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**Case**
I have made a form where you can make an order with articles. The articles are inserted in a table with another form. In these table the articles are saved with article code, description and the price.

The idea is that you select an article in the form to make the order. If you select the article (with a select input), the price is automatically filled in the "price" input field.

**Problem**
At the moment my problem is that when you select an article in one row, the script fills in the associated article price in all the other rows instead of only in the row where the select input is in.
I think i have to do something with the partent function in the Ajax code I use but I don't know how to do.

Can anyone give me some advice?

I use the following Ajax/jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var id = $(this).parent();
        jQuery('#Article_ID').live('change', function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url     : 'getData.php',
                type    : 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data    : $('#myForm').serialize(),
                success: function( data ) {
                       for(var id in data) {        
                              $(id).val( data[id] );
                       }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The getData file contains the following code:

```
$clientId = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['Article_ID'])) {
  $clientId = $_POST['Article_ID'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_connDatabase, $connDatabase);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($Article_ID, "int"));
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $connDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

$add1 = $row_Recordset1['description'];
$add2 = $row_Recordset1['price'];

$arr = array( 'input#description' => $add1, 'input#price' => $add2 );
echo json_encode( $arr );

mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
```

The form contains the following code for the rules:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
$(function(){
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#container').append('<div class="regel"><select id="Article_ID" name="Article_ID" style="width:17px; height:30px; border:none;margin-right:0px;"><option value="">Select</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select><input id="description" name="description[]' + '" type="text" class="field-l" style="width:425px"/><input id="price" name="price[]' + '" type="text" value="0.00" class="field-l" style="width:75px; margin-left:6px; text-align:right"/></p>' );  
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `the script fills in the associated article price in all the other rows instead of only in the row where the select input is in`

This is due to the fact that you append new row `onClick` ( `<div class="regel">..</div>`) with same IDs : `Article_ID`,`description`,`price`. Attribute `ID` must be unique.

Try. 
Change next (PHP):

```
$arr = array( 'input#description' => $add1, 'input#price' => $add2 );
echo json_encode( $arr );
```

to:

```
$arr = array( 'description' => $add1, 'price' => $add2 );
echo json_encode( $arr );
die;
```

Change `JS`:

```
    jQuery('#Article_ID').live('change', function(event) {
        var parent = $(this).parent(); // current `<div class="regel">`
        $.ajax({
            url     : 'getData.php',
            type    : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $('#myForm').serialize(),
            success: function( data ) {
                $(parent+" #description").val(data.description); // 
                $(parent+" #price").val(data.price);
            }
        });
    });
```